# meet some error after 'npm update -g'

Tags: node.js, npm

After npm update -g, some error when I input 'npm ls -g' in konsole. I don't how to solve it.Please help me, thank you. I want to reinstall npm and node, but I don't whether solve this problem.
OS is Slackware Linux

This is error.

```
/usr/lib
├─┬ flora-pac@0.0.3
│ └─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│   ├── minimist@0.0.10
│   └── wordwrap@0.0.2
├─┬ netease-player@0.1.1
│ ├── colorful@2.1.0
│ ├── keypress@0.2.1
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├─┬ player@0.1.8
│ │ ├── async@0.7.0
│ │ ├─┬ lame@1.1.0
│ │ │ ├── bindings@1.2.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ debug@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ └── ms@0.6.2
│ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
│ │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│ │ ├── pool_stream@0.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ speaker@0.0.10
│ │ │ ├── bindings@1.2.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ debug@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ └── ms@0.6.2
│ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
│ │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│ │ └── underscore@1.6.0
│ ├─┬ prompt@0.2.13
│ │ ├── pkginfo@0.3.0
│ │ ├─┬ read@1.0.5
│ │ │ └── mute-stream@0.0.4
│ │ ├── revalidator@0.1.8
│ │ ├─┬ utile@0.2.1
│ │ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ │ ├── deep-equal@0.2.1
│ │ │ ├── i@0.3.2
│ │ │ ├── ncp@0.4.2
│ │ │ └── rimraf@2.2.8
│ │ └─┬ winston@0.6.2
│ │   ├── async@0.1.22
│ │   ├── colors@0.6.2
│ │   ├── cycle@1.0.3
│ │   ├── eyes@0.1.8
│ │   ├── pkginfo@0.2.3
│ │   ├── request@2.9.203
│ │   └── stack-trace@0.0.9
│ ├─┬ request@2.34.0
│ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
│ │ │ ├── async@0.9.0
│ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│ │ │ └── punycode@1.3.1
│ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ └── term-canvas@0.0.5
├─┬ node-gyp@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.1
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├─┬ glob@4.0.5
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ └── once@1.3.0
│ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
│ ├─┬ minimatch@1.0.0
│ │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ ├─┬ nopt@3.0.1
│ │ └── abbrev@1.0.5
│ ├─┬ npmlog@0.1.1
│ │ └── ansi@0.3.0
│ ├── osenv@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ request@2.40.0
│ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
│ │ │ ├── async@0.9.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ └── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.1.1
│ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ ├── mime-types@1.0.2
│ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ ├── qs@1.0.2
│ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│ │ │ └── punycode@1.3.1
│ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
│ ├── rimraf@2.2.8
│ ├── semver@3.0.1
│ ├─┬ tar@1.0.0
│ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
│ └── which@1.0.5
├─┬ npm@1.4.9
│ ├── abbrev@1.0.4
│ ├── ansi@0.2.1
│ ├── ansicolors@0.3.2
│ ├── ansistyles@0.1.3
│ ├── archy@0.0.2
│ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
│ ├── char-spinner@1.0.1
│ ├── child-process-close@0.1.1
│ ├── chmodr@0.1.0
│ ├── chownr@0.0.1
│ ├─┬ cmd-shim@1.1.1
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│ │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0 invalid
│ │   └── minimist@0.0.8
│ ├─┬ columnify@0.1.2
│ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@0.2.2
│ │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.1.0
│ │ └─┬ wcwidth.js@0.0.4
│ │   └── underscore@1.6.0
│ ├── editor@0.0.5
│ ├─┬ fstream@0.1.25
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2 invalid
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0 invalid
│ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │ └── rimraf@2.2.8
│ ├─┬ fstream-npm@0.1.6
│ │ └─┬ fstream-ignore@0.0.7
│ │   └─┬ fstream@1.0.1 invalid
│ │     ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
│ │     ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │     ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│ │     │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │     └── rimraf@2.2.8
│ ├── github-url-from-git@1.1.1
│ ├── github-url-from-username-repo@0.1.0
│ ├── glob@3.2.9
│ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.2
│ ├── inflight@1.0.1
│ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├── ini@1.1.0
│ ├─┬ init-package-json@0.0.16
│ │ ├── promzard@0.2.1
│ │ └── semver@3.0.1 invalid
│ ├── lockfile@0.4.2
│ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.3.5
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ ├─┬ node-gyp@0.13.0
│ │ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.1 invalid
│ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │ │ └── rimraf@2.2.8
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.40.0
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.9.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ │ └── mime@1.2.11
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ ├── mime-types@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── qs@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│ │ │ │ └── punycode@1.3.1
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
│ │ └── semver@3.0.1 invalid
│ ├── nopt@2.2.1
│ ├── npm-cache-filename@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ npm-install-checks@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ npmlog@0.1.1 invalid
│ │ │ └── ansi@0.3.0
│ │ └── semver@3.0.1 invalid
│ ├─┬ npm-registry-client@0.4.8
│ │ ├── chownr@0.0.1
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2 invalid
│ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0 invalid
│ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │ ├── npm-cache-filename@1.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ npmlog@0.1.1
│ │ │ └── ansi@0.3.0
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.40.0
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.9.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ │ └── mime@1.2.11
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ ├── mime-types@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── qs@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│ │ │ │ └── punycode@1.3.1
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
│ │ ├── retry@0.6.0
│ │ ├── rimraf@2.2.8
│ │ ├── semver@2.3.2
│ │ └── slide@1.1.5
│ ├── npm-user-validate@0.0.3
│ ├─┬ npmconf@0.1.15
│ │ ├─┬ config-chain@1.1.8
│ │ │ └── proto-list@1.2.2
│ │ └── semver@2.3.2
│ ├── npmlog@0.0.6
│ ├── once@1.3.0
│ ├── opener@1.3.0
│ ├── osenv@0.0.3
│ ├── path-is-inside@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ read@1.0.5
│ │ └── mute-stream@0.0.4
│ ├─┬ read-installed@2.0.2
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2 invalid
│ │ ├─┬ read-package-json@1.2.6
│ │ │ ├── github-url-from-git@1.3.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ glob@4.0.5
│ │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ └── once@1.3.0
│ │ │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ │ └─┬ normalize-package-data@1.0.0
│ │ │   └── github-url-from-username-repo@0.2.0
│ │ ├── semver@3.0.1 invalid
│ │ ├── slide@1.1.5
│ │ └── util-extend@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ read-package-json@1.1.9
│ │ └─┬ normalize-package-data@0.2.13
│ │   └── semver@3.0.1 invalid
│ ├─┬ request@2.30.0
│ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.0
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ ├── async@0.2.9
│ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.9.15
│ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.3
│ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ ├── retry@0.6.0
│ ├── rimraf@2.2.6
│ ├── semver@2.2.1
│ ├─┬ sha@1.2.3
│ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.24
│ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.25
│ ├── slide@1.1.5
│ ├── sorted-object@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ tar@0.1.19
│ │ └─┬ fstream@1.0.1 invalid
│ │   ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
│ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │   ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│ │   │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │   └── rimraf@2.2.8
│ ├── text-table@0.2.0
│ ├── uid-number@0.0.5
│ └── which@1.0.5
└─┬ speaker@0.2.1
  ├── bindings@1.2.1
  ├─┬ debug@1.0.4
  │ └── ms@0.6.2
  ├── nan@1.2.0
  └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
    ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
    ├── inherits@2.0.1
    ├── isarray@0.0.1
    └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1

npm ERR! invalid: mkdirp@0.5.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/node_modules/mkdirp
npm ERR! invalid: mkdirp@0.5.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/mkdirp
npm ERR! invalid: graceful-fs@3.0.2 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs
npm ERR! invalid: fstream@1.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream-npm/node_modules/fstream-ignore/node_modules/fstream
npm ERR! invalid: semver@3.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/init-package-json/node_modules/semver
npm ERR! invalid: fstream@1.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/fstream
npm ERR! invalid: semver@3.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/semver
npm ERR! invalid: npmlog@0.1.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/node_modules/npmlog
npm ERR! invalid: semver@3.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/node_modules/semver
npm ERR! invalid: graceful-fs@3.0.2 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/graceful-fs
npm ERR! invalid: mkdirp@0.5.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/mkdirp
npm ERR! invalid: semver@3.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/semver
npm ERR! invalid: graceful-fs@3.0.2 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/graceful-fs
npm ERR! invalid: semver@3.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/semver
npm ERR! invalid: fstream@1.0.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I think you need to install newer version of node (later it come up with npm) and try again

Comment: I have a related issue on OS X: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238544/npm-err-invalid-strip-ansi0-2-2

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5913

Comment: `npm WARN cannot run in wd npm@1.4.9 node bin/npm-cli.js prune --prefix=. --no-global && rm -rf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j32 doc (wd=npm)
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.`