# npm ERR! invalid: strip-ansi@0.2.2

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, osx-mavericks

After upgrading `node` using `brew upgrade node`:

```
$ node -v
v0.10.30
```

I do a `npm update -g`:

```
$ npm -v
1.4.23
```

There is a ERR when `npm ls -g`:

```
npm ERR! invalid: strip-ansi@0.2.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/node_modules/strip-ansi
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed by:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5913