# What does 'invalid' mean when using npm list?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I am new to nodejs and i had just installed bower module globally. Ever since then, npm list command gives the following output which I searched for on the web but couldn't find any help :

```
**npm ERR! invalid: chalk@0.5.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk  
npm ERR! invalid: ansi-regex@0.2.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/has-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex  
npm ERR! invalid: configstore@0.3.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore  
npm ERR! invalid: object-assign@0.3.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/got/node_modules/object-assign  
npm ERR! invalid: registry-url@0.1.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-url  
npm ERR! invalid: strip-ansi@0.2.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/string-length/node_modules/strip-ansi  
npm ERR! not ok code 0**
```

The rest of the output is normal and lists the installed modules. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Check this answer. I had the same problem and this fixed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238544/npm-err-invalid-strip-ansi0-2-2

Answer (score 52):

I was getting this error having the same package installed both in "dependencies" and "devDependencies" with different versions.

Answer (score 21):

It means that something depends on, for example, `"async":"0.9.3"` but when they do `require("async")`, npm thinks that they'll get some other version. And also check that the dependencies and their versions listed in your `package.json` file are available.

If everything is right then you can solve this problem with

```
npm update
```

followed by

```
npm install.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? If `somelib`'s `package.json` depends on `"async":"0.9.3"`, surely npm should install async 0.9.3 into somelib/node_modules and `require("async")` should load up async 0.9.3. Could you let us know the kinds of circumstances it would load up a different version of async? Not doubting the helpfullness of your answer, I just don't fully understand.

Comment: @mikemaccana `somelib`'s `package.json` will always install the module version mentioned in `somelib`'s `package.json` locally to that module. So, it will not cause any problems for within the module. But in your project setup, if you have done something like `npm install async@0.6`, and in your `package.json` you have specified dependency as `async: 0.9.x` then this case arises.

Comment: Ah. My project setup would normally just run `npm install` (without any options) and install whatever's in `package.json` because all dependencies should be in `package.json` (or the shrinkwrap file).

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this error after installing a newer version of a module, without updating my package.json. So the package.json required the older version, while `npm list` was detecting a newer version in my `node_modules` directory.

Running the following command got me rid of the message.

`npm install {required_module}@{new_version} --save`

Answer (score 4):

#### Simplest answer

This can arise when the installed version of a package does not correspond to what `package.json` would install.

#### Example

Say you have specified `"axios": "0.19.2",` in your `package.json`, but after that you would install a specific version using `npm install axios@0.18.1`.

An `npm list | grep axios` would now yield

```
├─┬ axios@0.18.1 invalid
```

Follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696584/what-does-invalid-mean-when-using-npm-list/25760507#25760507) on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a related but different error (but ended up here, so I'm answering here) where after running `npm update` I'd get. (No such issue with `npm install`, fwiw)

```
myapp@1.0.0 /home/malcolm/myapp
├── beeminder@1.4.3  invalid
```

The `beeminder` package is one I maintain, so in my main app I had set its semver to `latest`. This seemed to work fine before, but I guess a newer version of `npm` doesn't like it.

I figured it was reasonable to just use `^1.4.3` because if I'm introducing new changes then I probably am changing my own code anyway. But if for some weird reason you need the latest latest of a package (including breaking changes!) then you can use `>=` as a prefix instead of `^`.