# Diagnosing npm’s “invalid” error in package list

Tags: npm, homebrew

When I do `npm list --global`, one package, phonegap, shows as invalid.

```
npm ERR! invalid: phonegap@5.0.0-0.28.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap
```

No other packages have any errors or problems. I’ve tried to look into this, and learned that the message means a [dependency is unfulfilled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696584/npm-list-giving-npm-err-invalid-output), but I can’t figure out which one. If I run `npm update --global phonegap` it exits cleanly, with no errors.

I originally installed npm & node via Homebrew, if that’s relevant. Here’s [my full list](http://pastebin.com/VnHykw7a) of globally installed packages.

How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the permissions for that package? I recently had a similar problem with global packages and it turned out to be a permissions issue

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: Thanks, but the question is really about understanding that message, not just making it go away.